# Polymorphism and the assignment operator in C

Tags: c, polymorphism

I saw the following saying about the assignment operator `=` in `C`.

> There are hidden polymorphism types in the assignment operator:
>
> 1. Coercion polymorphism - when we do implicit coercion between types.
> 2. Parametric polymorphism - Consider that the assignment operator is defined for each type in the PL (atomic and for user-defined with `struct` and `enum`).

I do understand the first saying about `Coercion`, but I don't understand why and how the assignment operator supports parametric polymorphism. Can I have an example which clarifies that statement?

**EDIT**: It was in a book of the concept of PLs (written in a different language). By saying that it has coercion polymorphism with implicit coercion looks something like:

```
int number = 4.5;
// number = 4
```

So saying that `C` does not have polymorphism isn't true.
By the way overloading is also polymorphism, and (of course) it is possible in `C`.

Comment: Such semantic details are often very specific to language. So please pick the actual language. C and C++ are often very different when it comes to such details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You say that C does not have any "polymorphism" but coercion is still polymorphism and the given examples proves that C does have it. Overloading is also a type of "polymorphism" which C supports.

Comment: I've not heard of coercion as being described as polymorphism.  I've not heard of assignment as being described as polymorphism.  That's not the usual terminology for those behaviors in C or C++.  I'd regard the source of this information as being suspect.

Comment: The coercion is not seen as polymorphism. Wikipedia definition of polymorphism is "provision of a single interface to entities of different types" or "the use of a single symbol to represent multiple different types". This is not the case in either of these. The only remotely polymorphic things in C are some macro hacks, including the use of `_Generic` in C11 and abstract data types using pointers to common substructure or `void`.

Comment: You say _"overloading is also polymorphism, and … it is possible in C"._  In default C, overloading is not possible.  There are two places where there is very limited support for it — in the [`<tgmath.h>`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.25) header and in the [`_Generic`  selection](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.1.1) mechanism. Neither is very powerful; neither is comparable to what's available in languages with direct support for overloading and polymorphism (except as a very pale, feeble subset of what other languages provide). There are no user-defined assignments.

Comment: Even many assembly languages have this polymorphism: something like "load reg, 10" considers reg's type and bit length and encodes 10 with an appropriate opcode.  It's so trivial. people don't tend to count it when discussing polymorphic features of languages, otherwise it'd just be "oh, all these languages have polymorphism", but it's only really useful if the *same code can be reused for different types*, and/or *calling code can implicitly dispatch to distinct type-appropriate code that you've written*.  C's macros actually allow the former: `#define F(X) X = 4.5`:  parametric polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case with technical and scientific terms, there is some diversity in the use and interpretation of the terms "polymorphic" and "polymorphism".  When people say that C does not support polymorphism, they are most likely to mean that it does not support *subtype* polymorphism, as it might be called by those who like to use the general term more broadly.  Contrary to your assertion, it also does not support *ad hoc* polymorphism, a.k.a. overloading.

Even if we accept type coercion as a form of polymorphism -- which is not a mainstream position -- in taking the claim that C does not support polymorphism out of its proper context, you have set up a straw man.  This is far more likely to irritate than to ingratiate, and I daresay it was not a wise strategy if you're actually looking for an answer as opposed to trying to start an argument.

As for your apparent question, however,

> I do understand the first saying about Coercion, but I don't understand why and how the assignment operator supports parametric polymorphism. Can I have an example which clarifies that statement?

I suppose the text means that the `=` operator is parameterized by the type of its left-hand operand, as the behavior of that operator varies, in a sense, depending on that type.  Specifically, the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the left-hand operand, and the specifics of the assignment can be interpreted to vary with that type as well.

But I find it dubious to characterize that as parametric polymorphism.  The hallmark of parametric polymorphism is normally an *explicit* parameter somewhere.  Templates are what people are typically talking about when they refer to parametric polymorphism in C++, and C does not have templates.  Nevertheless, C11 could be considered to have a limited form of parametric polymorphism in [generic selection](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.1.1).